# Protect API routes with NextJS and Passport: req.user undefined

Tags: javascript, authentication, session, passport.js, next.js

I am using NextJS for server-side rendering and I want to protect some "admin" pages on which I can do CRUD operations on my DB.

I succeded to add authentication on my website (with passport and next-connect, following this tutorial : https://hoangvvo.com/blog/next-js-and-mongodb-app-1).

But now I want to be able to avoid any "edit" operation if the user is not authenticated.

I feel like the best way to perform this is to check whether req.user exist or not in my /page/API files. But it's not working. Currently req.user is undefined. But the cookie is stored on my computer when I loggin correctly.

I've seen many issues like this one on stakoverflow. But only few is related to Nextjs. And none of them solved my problem (maybe because I'am a newbie in JS and authentication)

When I log in from auth API req.user exist and I get the cookie on my computer:

/pages/api/auth

req.user => OK

```js
    import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
    import middleware from '../../middleware/middleware';
    import passport from '../../lib/passport';
    import { extractUser } from '../../lib/api-helpers';
    
    const handler = nextConnect();
    handler.use(middleware);
    
    handler.post(passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
      res.json({ user: extractUser(req.user) });
      console.log(req.user) // IT WORKS
    });
    
    export default handler;
```

But then if I'm logged in and fetch data through any API, req.user is undefined.

An exemple of one of my API file:

/page/api/getList.js

```js
    import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
    import middleware from '../../middleware/middleware';
    
    const handler = nextConnect();
    handler.use(middleware);
    
    handler.post(async (req, res) => {
    
      console.log(req.user) // UNDEFINED
    
     // do something if req.user exist
    
    });

    export default handler;
```

------ if needed -------

my session middleware :

middleware/session.js

```js
    import session from 'express-session';
    import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo';
    import * as uuid from 'uuid';
    
    const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);
    
    export default function sessionMiddleware(req, res, next) {
      const mongoStore = new MongoStore({
        client: req.dbClient,
        stringify: false,
      });
      return session({
        secret: "this gonna rocks !",
        store: mongoStore,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
          maxAge: (1000 * 60 * 100)
        }
      })(req, res, next);
    }
```

my common middleware :

```js
    import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
    import passport from 'passport';
    import database from './database';
    import session from './session';
    
    const middleware = nextConnect();
    
    middleware
      .use(database)
      .use(session)
      .use(passport.initialize()) // passport middleware handles authenthentication, which populates req.user
      .use(passport.session());
    
    export default middleware;
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can someone tell me how to check whether the user is authenticated before doing any operation on the DB ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Would be grateful for an update if anyone managed to move past this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, the solution I found :

1. Make a middleware function and make sure when it hit error or response it should return handler. Like :

   ```
   const middleware = (handler) => async (req,res) =>{

   //Middleware function here
   //Code worked

   return (res.send(data), handler(req,res));

   //Error

   return res.send("error"), handler(req,res)

   }
   ```
2. In the handler file or api file:

   ```
   const handler = (req,res)=>{
   // Your code here
   }

   // How to export multiple middlewares    
   export default connectToMongo(middleware(handler));
   ```
3. Make sure to export middleware() inside connectToMongo(), this will make sure to make a connection to database first and then will check for middleware and then the handler.
4. No need to make connection in middleware function just make a function and use in your api and make sure pass it inside connectToMongo() function this will create connection.

I have tried to explain in a simple way I hope this will help you. If not please let me know.